# Sheets ArrayFormula to target multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

- In my one we are checking that the numbers in this row are between one and two.

I am supposed to populate ONE column based on the numbers on the corresponding row in columns A,B,C,D .

However my formula is doing the checks on on individual cells and pasting the result in multiple columns.

My formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBETWEEN('Sheet 2'!A2:D99,1,2),"Small", "FALSE"))
```

**Output with my formula**

```
FALSE   Small   FALSE   Small   Small
Small   Small   Small   FALSE   Small
Small   Small   Small   FALSE   Small
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

**My formula is reading**

```
5   2   3   1
2   2   2   2
2   2   2   1
```

**Output I wanted**

```
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

Can someone please help me to achieve my output thanks!

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include a copy of your sheet with the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=IF(COUNTIF(ISBETWEEN(A2:D2,1,2),TRUE)=COUNTA(A2:D2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]