# Please help me to adjust my formula ARRAYFORMULA multiple IFs?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, countif

I have a formula that needs to test on multiple conditions incl:

- If all numbers are between 1 and 2 then they are "Category A"
- If all numbers are between 2 and 3 but there is a single occurence of the number 4 then they are "Category B"

The category column is in a separate sheet where I will be pasting this formula.

Here is my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBETWEEN('Sheet 2'!G2:K2,1,2),"Category 1", IF(ISBETWEEN('Sheet2'!G2:K2,2,3) & COUNTIF('Sheet 2'!G2:K99,3)=1,"Category 2")))
```

My sample data:

```
1   7   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   1   3   2
```

This should return

```
FALSE 
TRUE (meets first condition)
TRUE (meets second condition)
```

Comment: how this differs from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489987/sheets-arrayformula-to-target-multiple-rows ?

Comment: I'm not clear on your existing rule #2. You said "If all numbers are between 2 and 3 but there is a single occurence of the number 4 then they are 'Category B'." And you said that `2 2 1 3 2` is Category B. But it consists of numbers between 1 and 2 and a single occurrence of the number `3`, not the number `4`. Do you mean that it may contain one instance of a number *up to 4* (in other words, one 3 or one 4)? And what is the *actual* score range possible? 1 - 9? 0 - 10? Other? And what is the Category C rule?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX((REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:E3),,9^9)), "[1-2 ]", )="")+
   (LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:E3),,9^9)), "[2-3 ]", ))=1)=1)
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Before I look into this, do you think this is feasible in the case where I need to add multiple categories for many different conditions?

Comment: so instead of True it was meant to be Category A/B or FALSE but this will go up to category C

Comment: @signupwithfacebook see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you player0! And is it feasible for me to continue to append conditions so instead of FALSE I will put another IF ?

Comment: @signupwithfacebook yes thats correct